# reverse-i-search à la Bash Ctrl-r

Tags: search, command-history

I would like to be able to search through the previous commands starting with `:` that I entered, using an interactive incremental search, as it is possible in some shells (example: with Ctrl-r in bash).

Comment: From reading through [`:help ex-edit-index`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#ex%2dedit%2dindex) it looks like there is no such feature in Vim. Note that if `wildmenu` is enabled the up arrow will only match with what you've typed (so `:help<Tab>` will complete only history items starting with `:help`), which is far more useful than bash's "fuzzy" `<C-r>` IMHO. It's also possible someone one wrote a plugin to do this, but I'm not aware of one (if you want to implement it yourself then look at `:help history-functions`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of such behaviour of libreadline, but since Vim 7.4.2268 you can navigate through search matches when `'incsearch'` option is on *without* leaving search mode via [<kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> keys](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-G), which combined with [command-line window](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-window) can give you experience similar to what you seek.

It's very easy if you know that you're going to use search right from the start:

[image: start in cmdline-window]

And requires several additional keystrokes to lift your input into search pattern if you realize you want to search in the middle of typing your command:

[image: start in command-line]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Up>` and `<Down>` at any time to recall previous commands starting with what you already typed.

See `:help history`.

Comment: yes, but that is not what I am looking for. I also know that if I enter the beginning of a previous command and hit <Up> I will recall previous command that share this beginning. But that is not an reverse incremental search because it is restricted to matching the beginning of the command.

Comment: That's all you get in Vim.